# how to use heatmap colors in a piechart

Tags: python, heatmap

I need a pie chart where the segments are colored in the same way as they are defined in my heatmap. Each segment of the pie chart represents a cell in my heatmap. I can create the heatmap and also the pie chart, but I'm unable to transfer the colors from the heatmap to my pie chart

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# Path to the Excel file
excel_file_path = "/content/Mappe1.xlsx"

# Read the Excel file
data_frame = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path)

# Access the data in the DataFrame
print(data_frame)

# Create the heatmap
cmap = sns.heatmap(data_frame, annot=True, cmap="inferno", fmt=".2f")  # fmt=".2f" for float                  values with 2 decimal places

plt.show()

# Number of rings from the Excel table
num_rings = len(data_frame.iloc[:, 0])

# List to store the width of each ring
ring_widths = []

# Loop to calculate and store the width of each ring
for i in range(1, num_rings + 1):
    ring_width = math.sqrt((math.pi / num_rings * i) / math.pi)
    ring_widths.append(ring_width)

# Size of the axis
size_axis = [25] * 4

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Calculate the circumference of the circle
circle_circumference = 2 * math.pi

# Start angle for the first ring (outermost ring)
start_angle = 25 - (360 * ring_widths[0] / circle_circumference)

# Extract color palette from a heatmap
cmap = sns.color_palette("inferno", num_rings)

# Loop to create the pie charts for all rings
for i in range(num_rings):
    radius = ring_widths[i]  # Radius based on the width of the current ring
    ax.pie(size_axis, radius=radius, startangle=start_angle,
           colors=[cmap[i]],  # Use the color palette for each ring
           wedgeprops=dict(width=0.2, edgecolor='w'))
    size_axis = [size * 0.8 for size in size_axis]  # Decrease the size of the axis for the next ring

# Labeling the axes
ax.text(0, 1.2, 'Axis 1', horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center', fontsize=10)
ax.text(-1.3, 0, 'Axis 2', horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center', fontsize=10)
ax.text(0, -1.2, 'Axis 3', horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center', fontsize=10)
ax.text(1.3, 0, 'Axis 4', horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center', fontsize=10)

print('List of Radii:', ring_widths)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.